# ClassCleanup Method Runs Too Late (or After All ClassInitialize methods)

Tags: unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

When running multiple `[TestClass]`es *at the same time*, why do the `[ClassCleanup()]` methods only get called at the very end?

File: UnitTest1.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {

    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

File: UnitTest2.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {

    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

The execution order is the following:

1. UnitTest2.ClassInit()
2. UnitTest2.TestMethod1()
3. UnitTest1.ClassInit()
4. UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
5. UnitTest2.ClassCleanup()
6. UnitTest1.ClassCleanup()

Notice that both [ClassCleanup] methods are executed at the end of the set; not after each TestClass is "done".

But I **expected** a different behavior:

1. UnitTest2.ClassInit()
2. UnitTest2.TestMethod1()
3. UnitTest2.ClassCleanup() *- Expected*
4. UnitTest1.ClassInit()
5. UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
6. UnitTest1.ClassCleanup() *- Expected*

Microsoft's Documentation - [ClassCleanupAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx) says, "Identifies a method that contains code to be used after all the tests in the test class have run and to free resources obtained by the test class. "

But it appears to be run/executed late!

How do I fix this?  Or find a way to execute a method from the same TestClass right before the next ClassInitialize method.